# Android virtual device not working

Tags: android, android-studio, intel, haxm

I am trying to get my android studio emulator working . But when I keep creating one and trying to run them I get these errors . `qemu-system-x86_64.exe` `Failed to allocate 4000000` or some errors that I forgot what they said . I read a previous answer on here to change :

```
hw.ramSize=1024 to 
hw.ramSize=1024MB
OR
hw.ramSize=512MB
```

I've tried this on every emulator that I have made but I keep getting the same errors . I have also read an answer here that said to check if my VT-x is enabled but when I go to my BIOS settings I keep getting told to make sure TPM is enabled , enable admin passwords and two other errors I forgot . I also cannot install Haxm on android studio . I am being told that haxm 6.0.5 is not compatible with windows . Can someone please help ? There is nothing else I know how to do .

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you running this on a 32 bit or 64 bit machine

Comment: Looks like either you are limited by 32 bit arch. But did you say you were running emulator earlier ? Can you try creating an AVD with 512MB ram, a low screen density (may be mdpi) and sans any other hardware emulation  (like camera etc.). The idea is to understand if this is something like a hardware limitation or a bug somewhere.

Comment: This is what I got `emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x20000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
Failed to allocate 20000000 memory`

Comment: From the logs here, HAXM is definitely installed and running. Your AVD RAM size should be less than or equal to the RAM size allocated to HAXM during installation. In your case 'Hax ram_size 0x20000000' which is 512MB i guess. Please rerun the Haxm installer and provide a higher RAM for HAXM like 1024MB. Go through this link  -https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is your chipset. It has been a while but last I checked AMD couldn't run the emulator on windows

Comment: So what should i do ?

Comment: Install a ubuntu virtual box, then install genymotion. https://docs.genymotion.com/Content/01_Get_Started/Installation.htm